# What does optional-TTL mean?

Tags: nikon, flash

I have a Sunpak PF30x on a Nikon D40. When I take pictures with the Sunpak flash, I notice the image data has "Optional-TTL" as the flash mode.

Comment: Did the flash fire?

Comment: Yes the flash did fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional-TTL means you're using an accessory flash instead of the built in flash, but still using the through the lens metering to control it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of how your model is setup?

This flash unit supports flash exposure compensation which allows you to adjust output independently of the i-TTL.

Disclaimer: I don't have one of these units. Just what I noticed from a simple websearch about this product.